# No Git, como faço pra editar a descrição de um commit já efetuado?

Tags: git, versionamento

No caso de precisar alterar a descrição de um *commit*, para deixar a descrição mais clara, ou especificar a qual *issue* ele está vinculado.

Gostaria de saber como faço para editar a mensagem que acompanha o *commit*, depois dele ter sido executado.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

É Tranquilo Guilherme, faz o seguinte

```
git commit -m "Nova mensagem que vai substituir a anterior" --amend
```

Com isso você vai sobrescrever a mensagem antiga de seu `commit`!

E ainda se o commit não for o ultimo, você pode editar um commit antigo utilizando o modo interativo do commit

```
git rebase -i
```

Serve também para caso você tenha feito alguma alteração e quer que esta faça parte do `commit` anterior!

por exemplo:
  Você fez um `commit` para fechar a issue X, mas viu que faltava alguma coisa, realizou essa operação, mas não quer ter dois commits fechando a mesma issue, então você mescla as duas em um só `commit` usando o `amend`

Ah e isso só funciona direito se você ainda não deu `push` desse `commit`

Comment: No caso de querer corrigir commits antigos(que já tenham sido enviados pro servidor) apenas pra ficar documentado, não rola então?

Comment: Não... cara. Não rola =\

Comment: @Guilherme rolar acho que até rola (com `git rebase -i HEAD^10` e `git push -f`, para os últimos 10 commits), mas em geral é desencorajado reescrever o histórico no servidor -- provavelmente vai dar problema no repo de todo mundo. Mas talvez fazendo num branch separado, e sincronizando com todo mundo depois, vai de boa.

Comment: Essa parte sobre o que esta no servidor foi mais por curiosidade mesmo. Valeu.

Answer (score 23):

## Editando o último commit

Basta fazer `git commit --amend -m "nova mensagem"`.

## Editando um commit na linha do tempo

Se o commit que quiser editar não for o último você pode editá-lo via *rebase* interativo:

`git rebase -i`

Seu editor de texto irá iniciar. Troque no texto a palavra `pick` por `reword` (ou só `r`) do commit desejado, exemplo:

```
pick fef7501 Primeiro commit.
reword 90d77f4 Segundo commit.
pick b82a17f Terceiro commit.

# Rebase 3620553..b82a17f onto 3620553
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Salve e o arquivo e feche seu editor. Seu editor será iniciado novamente, dessa vez com a mensagem original do commit a ser modificado. Modifique-a, salve e feche o editor.

## Ponto importante: você está rescrevendo histórico

Tanto ao fazer um `--amend` simples ou um `reword` com *rebase* você estará rescrevendo o histórico do git. Isto é, o git gerará um novo SHA1 para o commit. Você **não** conseguirá, por exemplo, realizar um *push* pois parte da árvore original de commits não está presente na do seu branch local.

No caso do *rebase* **todos** os commits que fazem parte do rebase serão rescritos (novo SHA1) **mesmo se não alterados**.

A não ser que você force o *push* (`git push -f`) o git rejeita commits que rescrevem seu histórico.

A recomendação que eu deixo é: **Somente rescreva commits que não estão em outras árvores (commits que ainda não foram em um push). Caso contrário saiba o que está fazendo.**.

Answer (score 7):

Se for o último commit, use `git commit --amend -m "Nova mensagem"`.
Não é recomendado fazer isso se você já tiver dado um *push* do commit.

Answer (score 2):

Outro jeito de fazer isso, talvez mas simples, é com *git-gui*. No menu pode fazer *Commit->Amend Last Commit*. Daí vai aparecer um sob-menu onde pode editar o texto do ultimo commit; quando terminar, é só apertar "Commit".